# Why is some software not appearing in the "available software" options?

Tags: 12.04, software-sources, quodlibet

I have installed and used some applications such as Quod Libet and others on Ubuntu 12.04. When I go under settings to tell Ubuntu which software to use when opening specific files, Quod Libet and others are not in the selection. Even when I click "Show Other Applications" it is not listed as one I can use. Now if I go through Quod Libet, I can tell it to play that file just fine so I know it will play, for instance .flac files, but why is it not showing up so I can select it as my default music client?

Thanks and apologies if this is already in another thread. I wasn't sure how to phrase the question.

Comment: How did you install the software? If you didn't do it via the Software Center or by apt-get, you may have such problems.

Comment: I installed the software via the Software Center. For Quod Libet, I installed it from the Software Center and have removed Rhythmbox from my machine as well through the Software Center. I have done this on 3 different machines and neither of them will allow me to make Quod Libet my default music player - its not even in the list of choices. I am having issues with Asunder CD Ripper as well not being in the list of software. Both are under the Applications Menu but not under available software to run certain files or make default options.

Comment: Shot in the dark ... Could you look for a `.desktop` file related to Quod Libet in `/usr/share/applications`? If there is one, open it with a text editor and look for lines that may read `NotShowIn=Unity` or whatever desktop environment you are using. If there is such a line, save this .desktop file to ~/.local/share/applications and then comment out that line with a `#`. Save the file. Then see if you see it in the list of choices.